# Python cv2, changing camera resolution

Tags: python, opencv, debian

I am trying to get a very simple `VideoCapture` going with OpenCV, where I am able to change the resolution in between pictures.

My setup:

- Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- Python 3.9.2
- OpenCV 4.5.1

Already on the simplest step, OpenCV is giving me warnings I do not understand

```python
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Results in

```
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (961) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
```

I searched this warning, but I only find links to an OpenCV issue that should already be resolved (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63091548/gstreamer-warning-cannot-query-video-position-status-0-value-1-duration-1)).

Anyway the warning is not prohibitive, as I am able to see images from the camera, and I am able to downsize the camera rresolution from `3264x2448` to `640x480` using `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)` and `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)`.
The true issue occurs when I try to change the frame size back to the original:

```python
print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
# Prints: 3264.0 2448.0

org_w = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
org_h = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, org_w)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, org_h)
print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
```

This results in a bunch of warnings and the width and height values are set to `0x0` instead:

```
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1824) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Internal data stream error.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (536) startPipeline OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1085) setProperty OpenCV | GStreamer warning: no pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (992) getProperty OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: no pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (992) getProperty OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: no pipeline
0.0 0.0
```

And then `cv2.imshow` fails ofc.
Is this not the proper way to change camera resolution between pictures? Should I leave the camera in the original `3264x2448` and just use `cv2.resize` to reduce the image size after the image is taken?

Comment: Does your camera support 3264x2448 sizes ? The question seems not about the warning but setting width and height of the camera, so I suggest you to update your question accordingly. You may also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71523770/11048887)

Comment: Yes 3264x2448 is supported, it is also the default initial setting. The problem arises when I set a lower resolution and then go back to the starting resolution. 
Ok I will see if I can change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010313/opencv-videocapture-doesnt-work-ubuntu).
Observing that my OpenCV was built with `v4l2` the issue disappeared with

```python
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L2)
```

Build info can be found with

```python
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```